# Adding an array of shapes into a layer in kineticjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, kineticjs

I'm trying to attach an array of shapes to layer in kineticJS, so far this is what I've done:

```
elementContainer = {
    start: buildCircle(75, 75),
    activity: buildActivity(150, 50),
    end: buildCircle(250+25, 50+25)
 };
```

when I try to add the array like this

```
linesLayer.add(elementContainer);
```

I get an exception with the following message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'getType'
>   kinetic.min.js:4 Kinetic.Util.addMethods._validateAdd kinetic.min.js:4
>   Kinetic.Util.addMethods.add kinetic.min.js:3 (anonymous function)
>   (index):163 jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-2.1.0.js:4371 elemData.handle

[this is the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pedromullerrw/5WpP5/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As lavrton said, each element must be added individually, but you may want to use a loop in case you ever need to change the number or names of elements in `elementsContainer` instead of hard coding them.

```
for (var key in elementContainer) {
    layer.add(elementContainer[key]);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ze6nj/

Answer (score 0):

Add them separetly:

```
layer.add(elementContainer.start).add(elementContainer.activity).add(elementContainer.end);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5WpP5/2/